# Add existing has_many (current_user) on record save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to save a new record and on that record save, associate a has_many to it.

**building.rb**

```
has_many :users
```

**user.rb**

```
belongs_to :building
```

**buildings_controller**

```
def new
    @building = Building.new(user_ids: current_user.id)
  end

...
def building_params
      params.require(:building).permit(:address, :user_id, :user_ids)
    end
```

When I save, the record isn't adding the current_user to the new building record.

Comment: Just wondering the database structure. In your code, building has_many users, as my understanding, users table should have a column building_id, instead of the buildings table have a column user_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to associate the two. In the `create` action (instead of the `new` action) you can do something like this...

```
  @building = Building.new(building_params)
  @building.users << current_user

  if @building.save
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  end
```

Keep in mind that `@building` in the `new` action is just used to build the form, whereas the `@building` in the create action is used to save the record with the attributes provided from the form.